# Why didn't Mansley need to recite a code before activating the nuclear launch in "The Iron Giant"?

Tags: the-iron-giant

Towards the end of the film "The Iron Giant", after being convinced that the Giant never intended to harm anyone, Rogard tells the army to stand down. However, Mansley

> Grabs the walkie-talkie from Rogard and yells "Launch the missile now!", and the crew on the submarine dutifully do so.

Why didn't Mansley need to recite a launch code to prove his authority (which he didn't have) before the missile was launched?

Comment: Because the missile commander was scared by the 50 foot death bot? Someone obviously let their emotions take over their standard procedure.

Comment: I had been under the presumption that the general had already arranged everything that was needful for the missile to be launched.  Being in the middle of a live battlefield and at one moment under heavy fire it might seemed like the thing to do.  But I also have no idea what actual missile procedures are in place, nor what they were in the 50s(?) setting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a combination of reasons, which boil down to: General Rogard had already prepped and authorized the launch, and all that was left was to say "Go".

(did a bit of digging to mix with my comment and get a decent answer)

First off, the [Permissive Action Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permissive_Action_Link) system that most people think of when they think "launch codes" wasn't widely implemented until 1962.  Before that firing control was whatever security system the general in charge of the nuclear weapon thought was necessary and functional, and that could be anything from a prototype PAL to the classic twin-key thing.  The movie takes place in 1957, so anything goes.

Second, and this is more speculative of the off-screen elements but I think fits the situation, the General was in the middle of a battlefield.  His force was engaged trying to remove an extreme threat with unknown capabilities and was taking heavy fire with civilians at risk, and potentially more consequences if he can't contain the situation (that he created, but he does get that in hindsight).  So when Mansley convinced him to pull out a nuke, he would have done the equivalent of cocking the gun and putting his finger on the trigger by giving all the needed authorizations and commands in the breather he had (I think the Giant had shrugged off the battleship and was moving to retaliate at the time).  His tactics would have tried to lure the Giant away from the town before firing, but he would have prepared to sacrifice himself and the town if he saw no other option to prevent the Giant from rampaging elsewhere.

Third - and this is very easily missable, I missed it myself (credit to @Omegacron) - if you listen carefully to the scene, right after the General orders his men to stand down, he starts radioing the submarine, presumably to tell them the same thing.  It's in the background while Mansley and the Iron Giant are exchanging death glares.  So when Mansley grabs the radio, the sub crew already has good reason to expect that it's General Rogard on the line.  Between radio distortion and Mansley's hysterical hollering, it's actually not a surprise that they didn't realize Rogard hadn't given that order.

Rogard vastly overestimated Mansley's competence (which is the polite way to say the man was a tool) and failed to see how controlled by fear the man was, or he would have kept a tighter grip on his nuke and his radio.

Comment: Good answer +1 for calling Mansley a tool

Comment: Thanks for providing the additional research, I didn't know about that :D

Comment: Gonna award a bounty on this because it was so good

Comment: @MikasaPinata - okay! Many thanks.

Comment: Good answer. You may also want to add that the General had authorized the nuke launch earlier, then a second before Mansley grabbed the radio, the General radioed the sub and said "Nautilus, this is General Rogard..." to cancel the launch. The sub commander had no way of knowing that Rogard was going to cancel, or that it wasn't Rogard screaming "Launch the missile!!!"

Comment: @Omegacron - didn't remember that, but replayed through and you're right, kinda gets lost in the background noise but it's there.  Adding it in.